# Number of connections to RabbitMQ when using Django with Celery on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery, cloudamqp

I'm trying to understand what is happening between Web-Dynos, Worker-Dynos and RabbitMQ on my Heroku-hosted backend.

I notice that I have over 10 connections to RabbitMQ, although I so far I'm using one Web-Dyno and one Woker-Dyno. I am using greenthreads (eventlet) and expect to have one connection per Web- or Worker-Dyno.

This is my worker's start from Procfile:

`celery -E -A proj worker -B -l info --maxtasksperchild=1000`

In my case I can have over 10 open connections:
[image]

Here is also list of my queues (`celery` seems to be used for queuing the tasks, not quite sure what  the other two are for):
[image]

I've tried playing with `BROKER_POOL_LIMIT` and it does not seem to help. Right now `BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1` and the number of connections is 10.

Can it be caused by having eventlet instead of usual gunicorn-workers?

Comment: You have to limit the number of workers with `-w` and the concurrency with `-c`

Comment: I have concurrency set to 4 processes (defaults to the number of CPUs) and have 4 web workers. If I use BROKER_POOL_LIMIT * (gunicorn-workers * web dynos + worker dynos * concurrency) formula, I should never get more than 1*(1*4 + 1*4)=8 connections.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but this could be due to mingle and gossip. Did you try --without-mingle and --without-gossip? Also, curious to know, which monitoring tool is this?

Comment: @arjun27 This monitoring tool offered by AMPQ - a RabbitMQ SAAS provider